# Pasar variable cualitativa a cuantitativa

Tags: r

Quisiera pasar una variable cualitativa a cuantitativa para poder utilizar el algoritmo KNN. 
La variable está incluída en un dataframe. En éste caso la variable es "sexo" y puede ser "male" o "female". Quisiera que pasara a 1 y 0 respectivamente.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También puedes usar la coerción de datos logicos a numéricos:

```
df$sexo_cuanti <- as.numeric(df$sexo == "male")
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `ifelse`

```
 df$sexo_cuanti <- ifelse(df$sexo == "male", 1, 0)
```

Suponinego que el data frame se llama df. 
La nueva variable `df$sexo_cuanti` será 1 si en la variable `sexo` el valor es `male` y 0 si NO es `male` (si el `female` o si tiene otro valor, por eso esto funciona si tu variable `df$sexo` solo tiene los valores `male` o `female`).